# google analytics and lead capture

Tags: google-analytics

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

I have a landing page with a lead capture form (Name email phone). I am running adwords campaigns to capture these leads.

I want to know is there any way I can tag each lead with the keyword and campaign it came through. This way i will be able to know which campaigns are generating quality leads for me.

If there is any sample code available it will be great.

P.S My campaigns are autotagged so I can't capture data from URL and UTM parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to [define a goal](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55515) on that lead.
You can define this goal :

- on the URL where your visitor are redirect after the form validation if there is one
- if not on an event you wil [add](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) on form submit

Then get all the statistics in the Analytics Advertising reports.

note : don't forget to activate [autotagging](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55590) on your Adwords campaigns.

Comment: Okay and That will help in knowing which exact lead came from which keywords? I am not sure how can you please explain?

Comment: Your question does not specify a need for a one-one tracking... And the response is : Analytics is not the right tools for that.